# Call the jsp pages based on javascript if else conditions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a jsp form like this.

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="a.jsp" target="menu_page"
    onSubmit="return(setSearchParameters);">
    <tr>
        <td class="srchtext">&nbsp;&nbsp;Search No. :</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="h_trans_code" class="password" onFocus="this.select();" size="18"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

After inputting the search no and click the search button it will call a.jsp page. But Now I want to check the length of Search No & if the Search No length is equal to 14 digit, it should call the new jsp page "b.jsp" else should call "a.jsp" using javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this? Note that this is basic JavaScript, no need to play with JSP nor Java code at all.

Comment: Actually this isn't something you should be with JavaScript at all. Modify a.jsp to check the number and redirect to b.jsp, if it's not valid.